# play command doesn't work when inside of an existing sbt project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

So I have an existing sbt project setup:

```
common
services
project/build.scala
build.sbt
```

Now when inside this folder, I want to create a play application called 'web'.

I get this error:

```
error] Not a valid command: new (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: new
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: new (similar: name, run, runner)
[error] new
[error]    ^
```

The play command works just fine if I try the same thing in a new folder.

How can I get the play command to work inside of an existing sbt project?

I'm using sbt .13

Comment: Is it already existing Play project?

Comment: @goral No its a regular sbt project, not play.  I want to create a play inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the project outside of the current structure, then move the created directory where you want it to live?

Comment: Yes I can, but I am not sure why this isn't working.  And if there will be issues running play in the future even if I do that.